# the running application have different layout than the preview

Tags: android-studio

While running the application the design layout is not same as in the preview as all the widgets are overlapping at the top-left corner no matter where I place them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your code please. 
Perhaps you're using a Relativelayout without specifying the position with its attribute.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide you xml code.
and in my case i faced the same issue. when i using the relative layout. just use linear layout and check it again...